# How to update sql column based on previous column values

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have a table and its columns are id(int), order_id(int), partner_id(int)

Now I want to increment order_id based on partner_id ,
For Example
for partner 1, order_id's are 1,2,3
then if partner 2 is placing the order, the order_ids should start again from 1 and not from 4.

What is the best way to do so in mysql ? Should I read the last order id for a particular partner from db every time I want to create a new order ?

I am using mysql and sequelize

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a similar scenario for my case I 1st created a column on the order table called `order_number`.

Then created a `mysql function` to get the expected `order_number` base on parameter of the function and the order table.

Then on insert I just called the mysql function with appropriate parameter.

Here is what the mysql function looked like in my case:

**Creating the function:**

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION `get_order_number`(partner_id VARCHAR(255)) RETURNS int(10)
BEGIN
        DECLARE getCount INT(10);

        SET getCount = (
            SELECT COUNT(id)
            FROM order_table
            WHERE `partner_id` = partner_id
        ) + 1;

        RETURN getCount;
    END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

.

.

**Implementation:**

```
INSERT INTO (
  id, 
  order_id, 
  pertner_id
) VALUES (
  NULL,
  get_order_number(10),  -- 10 is partner_id
  10 -- 10 is partner_id
);
```

.

.

**Explanation of the function**

1st pass `partner_id` as parameter for the function.

2nd inside the function I created a `select` query to get the number of how many orders have this partner created.

Finally adding one (1) with the returned number to get the last value.

.

.

**Declaimer:**

I have been using this function for over 3 years and have not got any issues yet. But this function has a weak point: When I submit the form simultaneously in two form/page at the same time (in millisecond) I get a deadlock error error for calling same function at the same time. Since I have moderate users I have not faced this error yet in real life situation.

I am using this function in plain mysql driver with node js, have not tested with sequelize.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I was also thinking somewhat same, but not with mysql function.
Thanks.

Comment: If you implement this process in sequelize please do share the solution as well, i need to implement this type of code in sequelize.

Comment: Sure , will share the solution.